# Any trick for evaluating $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(\theta) + \frac{i}{2}\sin(\theta)\right)^7$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Expressions of the form $(a\cos(\theta) + bi\sin(\theta))^n$ come up from time to time in applications of complex analysis, but to my knowledge the De Moivre's formula can only be applied with $a = b$. Is there some trick to deal with the case of $a \neq b$, for example when the expression is $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(\theta) + \frac{i}{2}\sin(\theta)\right)^7$?

Comment: There is something called [De moivres](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) theorem. Or you can just use basic binomial theorem. Then, use trigonometric identities.

Comment: This I just know but you can pair the thing as $(\cos(30^\circ)\cos(\theta) + \sin(30^\circ)\sin(\theta))^7$. Maybe that can take you somewhere

Comment: They are formulas for sin(a$\pm$b) and cos(a$\pm $b).

Comment: @NεoPλατo Yeah I'm an idiot, should have checked the arcus functions first...

Comment: @NeoPlato there is an $i$ in there as well.

Comment: @Empy2 But of course. Except now I can't edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, from de Moivre's theorem, we have:
$$\cos x=\frac {e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$ and $$\sin x =\frac {e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$$
Then, $$S=(a\cos x+ib\sin x)^n=\frac {((a+b) e^{ix}+(a-b) e^{-ix})^n}{2^n}$$
Hence, from the Binomial Theorem,
$$S=\frac {\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {n}{r} (a+b)^{n-r}(a-b)^r e^{i(n-2r)x}}{2^n}$$
Since $e^{i(n-2r)x}=\cos ((n-2r)x)+i\sin ((n-2r)x)$ we have:
$$S=\left(\frac {\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {n}{r} (a+b)^{n-r}(a-b)^r \cos((n-2r) x)}{2^n}\right)+i\left(\frac {\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {n}{r} (a+b)^{n-r}(a-b)^r \sin ((n-2r) x)}{2^n}\right)$$

Thus it is evident what this particular case shall simplify to.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

$$ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}} \cos \theta = \cos 30 \cos \theta= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos(30 - \theta)+\cos \left(30+ \theta \right) \right] =\frac12 (b+a)$$

$$ \frac12 \sin \theta= \sin(30) \sin \theta= \frac12 \left[\cos \left( 30 - \theta\right)- \cos (30+ \theta )\right]=\frac12 (b-a)$$

We have:

$$\frac{1}{2^7}\left[ (a+b) + i(b-a)\right]^7$$

Call $a+b=u=\sqrt{3} \cos \theta$, $b-a=v= \sin \theta$, then for the complicated part:

$$ \left[ u+iv\right]^7 = (u^2+v^2)^{\frac72} \left[\frac{u+iv}{(u^2 + v^2)^{\frac12}} \right]^7=(u^2 +v^2)^{\frac72} e^{i7( \tan^{-1} \frac{v}{u}) }$$

Now back substitute and simplify.

Answer (score 2):

**Long Comment:**

For your particular problem there is a small tiny tiny algebraic simplification as

$$T=\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{3}\right) \cos (\theta )-i \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{3}\right) \sin (\theta )=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \cos (\theta )-\frac{1}{2} i \sin (\theta )\tag1$$
or
$$T=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right) \cos (\theta )-i \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right) \sin (\theta )=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \cos (\theta )-\frac{1}{2} i \sin (\theta )\tag2$$

Rewriting (1) as

$$S=\left( \sin \left(\omega\right) \cos (\theta )-i \cos \left(\omega\right) \sin (\theta )\right)^n \tag3$$

we can get to
$$S= \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)^n (\sin (\theta +\omega )+i \sin (\theta -\omega ))^n \tag4$$

and likewise for (2)

$$S=\left(\cos (\theta ) \cos \left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right)+i \sin (\theta ) \sin \left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right) \right)^n$$

we get
$$S= \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)^n \left(\cos \left(\theta +\frac{\omega }{2}\right)+i \cos \left(\theta -\frac{\omega }{2}\right)\right)^n$$

Using @Buraian 's methods we have the interesting general result for (3)

$$S=\left( \sin \left(\omega\right) \cos (\theta )-i \cos \left(\omega\right) \sin (\theta )\right)^n=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)^n\left(1-\cos (2 \theta ) \cos (2 \omega )\right)^{n/2} e^{ \left(i \,n \tan ^{-1}(\sin (\theta +\omega ),\sin (\theta -\omega ))\right)}\tag5$$

where $\tan ^{-1}(x,y)=\tan ^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ gives the angle of the point $[x,y]$ and where $\sin ^2(\theta -\omega )+\sin ^2(\theta +\omega )$ simplifies to $1-\cos (2 \theta ) \cos (2 \omega )$.